# how to import custom typings into a vscode js project

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I have a js project and I use vscode. For type checking I use `//@ts-check`.
One dependency, [thinky](https://github.com/neumino/thinky), does not have type information but I found [@emtypes/thinky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emtypes/thinky) (github repo is deleted).

In vscode, I get a hint, that I should create a **.d.ts* file with `declare module 'thinky'`. Doing that, removes the errors but just defines `thinky` as `any`, which is not helpful.

**How do I import the custom typings from *node_modules/@emtypes/thinky/index.d.ts*?**

Doing a [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+import+custom+typings+into+a+js+project) shows lots of examples of how to import a js project into a ts project but I need the other way around. I also found, [Is it possible to use custom type definitions in an ES6 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286781/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-type-definitions-in-an-es6-project/44313067#44313067), but that is about **creating** types for a js project, and I need to import custom *typings* for an imported js library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/722bdbec8e887aae7924c1f0d3edca48b7424e5f/pages/Type%20Checking%20JavaScript%20Files.md#import-types

In the file where I use thinky, I have added:

```js
/**
 * @typedef { import('@emtypes/thinky').Thinky } thinky
 */

/** @type {thinky} */
let thinky
```